# transform text to json

Tags: javascript, bash

I have a huge list like this:

```
Title / Company

Subtitle

Description (usually long)
(line break)
(line break)
(line break)
(next object like above)
```

If there is no company name, the Title is the Company name and the Title.

I need to transform this to a json-object like this:

```
{
  "id": "title",
  "title": "Title",
  "subtitle": "Subtitle",
  "company": "Company",
  "titleImage": "_title.png",
  "text": "Description",
  "hmtl": "",
  "tags": []
},
```

What's the fastest way to do different transformation tasks like this with javascript/bash-scripts/other tools and how would that look?

Comment: do you handle this pragmatically???

Comment: as pragmatic as possible, which is why I turn to SO

Comment: If  the file is really large in size of 100xMb range, then you would probably want to use Node.js streams. Without at-least one accurate and complete sample data, we won't be able to help you much.

Comment: show us a little real example to claiming help :-)

Answer (score 0):

That's a 2 step process:

1. you have to parse your original file (with some regex), store the infos in an object (or a list of objects maybe)
2. dump your json

```
# parse your data...

JSON.stringify(parsed_data)
```

You understood it: the hardest part is the parse the original thing.

With so little examples, we can't really help you, and that's not the purpose of StackOverflow anyway. If you have trouble while coding the first step, then ask (don't forget show us what you've done) and plenty of people (including me) will be willing to help you out!